# Como puedo validar fechas por rangos

Tags: php, postgresql

Buenas que tal estoy tratando de validar fechas por rangos pero tengo un problemas con la función ya que no me reconoce los rangos por que no obtengo ningún tipo de respuesta a continuación paso mi código:
En resumen lo que el código hace es validar los datos para poder mostrarlos que se ejecutan de las dos tablas de base de datos.

```
function check_in_range($date_start, $date_end, $date_now) {
  
    $date_start = strtotime($date_start);
    $date_start = strtotime($date_end);
    $date_now = strtotime($date_now);
       if (($date_now >= $date_start) && ($date_now <= $date_end))
           return true;
       return false;
    }
    
    $edificio2019 = pg_query($conexion2, "SELECT gid, no, tipo_inmueble, fecha_dia from dept_loc_ofi where (fecha_dia >='2019-01-01' AND fecha_dia <= '2019-12-31') ORDER BY no ASC");
    
    while ($edi2019 = pg_fetch_row($edificio2019)) {

    $gid = $edi2019[0];
    $nro = $edi2019[1];
    $tipo = $edi2019[2];
    $date_now = date($edi2019[3]);  
    //echo $date_now;

    $depo2019 = pg_query($conexion2, "SELECT gid, no, locales from dept_ofi where (fecha_dia >='2019-01-01' AND fecha_dia <= '2019-12-31')");

    while ($dpto2019 = pg_fetch_row($depo2019)) {

        $gid1 = $dpto2019[0];
        $nro1 = $dpto2019[1];
        $local = $dpto2019[2];
        $date_start = date('2019-01-01');
        $date_start = date('2019-12-31');
        
        //echo $nro."=".$nro1;
        if ($nro == $nro1) { 
            
            if ($tipo=='Local') {
                
                    
                    if (check_in_range($date_start, $date_end, $date_now)) {
                        
                    
                    $edificios_loc2019 = pg_query($conexion2, "SELECT edificio, point_x, point_y, no FROM dept_ofi where (fecha_dia >='2019-01-01' AND fecha_dia <= '2019-12-31') AND  locales = 1 ORDER BY no ASC ");
echo "pasa";

                    
                    }else{ echo"no pasa";}
        
        }
    

    }

    }
    
}
```

Este es el código con el que estoy trabajando el código trabaja bien la única parte que no esta marchando es la parte de la función de  validación por fecha.

Agradecería mucho si alguien puede ver algún error que pase por alto o si en algún lugar estoy cometiendo algún error, gracias..

Comment: En la función check_in_range tienes definida dos veces $date_start, la segunda debería ser $date_end, asi que nunca va a cumplir la condición, parece un error tipográfico.

Comment: Si lo vi hace rato, se me fue pero también logre solucionarlo... gracias